# Как создать кастомный макрос в конфлюенсе, который использует rss

Tags: xml, rss

Как создать кастомный макрос в конфлюенсе, который использует рсс фиды? Стандартный макрос слишком минимальный. Или, может быть, кто подскажет, как посмотреть темплейт стандартного макроса, чтобы по его образу и подобию написать юзерский. Или кто-то встречал туториалы по данному вопросу (можно на английском). Как создавать простые макросы я знаю. Заранее очень благодарен, бо очень надо, а инфы по данному вопросу не смог нагуглить ни на английском, ни на русском.

Comment: [Writing Confluence Plugins](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/writing-confluence-plugins)

Comment: Примеры плагинов можно поискать на [GitHub'e](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=confluence++plugin&type=Repositories)